# How this uint accept Address value in this smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Can anyone Explain me how uint variable accept address in this smart contract

// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0.
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

library CairoConstants {
uint256 public constant FIELD_PRIME =
0x800000000000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
}

As per my Knowledge Uint Only accept unsigned integer values so why on Compilation it not throws an Error Message

Please Clear my Doubt

Thank You

Hello Everyone,

Can anyone Explain me how uint variable accept address in this smart contract

// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0.
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

library CairoConstants {
uint256 public constant FIELD_PRIME =
0x800000000000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001;
}

As per my Knowledge Uint Only accept unsigned integer values so why on Compilation it not throws an Error Message

Please Clear my Doubt

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You will need to post your code, especially the line that is throwing the error so someone can actually help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of a given hex value is 20bytes, the compiler thinks it's an address, otherwise, it thinks it's a number.
So if you use `0x8000000000000110000000000000000000000000`, it might throw an error since it's an address, but in your code, the given value is not an address.
In addition, if the length of the value is 39 or 41 hex digits, it also throws an error since the compiler thinks it looks like an address but there's a typo.